# Execute a remote script on ESXi from a local RHEL

Tags: shell, vmware

I have scp 'd a script from RHEL to ESXi /vmfs/volumes/datastore/script.sh

Is there a way, I can SSH to this ESXi from my RHEL execute the script and then exit the ESXi shell.
RHEL is bash and ESXi is sh while `echo$0`

I tried couple of methods:

```
ssh root@esxi-ip '/vmfs/volumes/datastore/script.sh'

ssh root@esxi-ip << EOT
> /vmfs/volumes/datastore/script.sh
> EOT
```

Most of these fail. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: define 'fail'.  What went wrong? What feedback did you get from your execution environment?

Comment: For 
`ssh root@esxi-ip '/vmfs/volumes/datastore/script.sh'
sh: -le: argument expected`

For
`ssh root@esxi-ip << EOT`

`Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Password:`

`sh: -le: argument expected`

Comment: It appears then that there is a syntactical error in the script.  What happens if you `ssh` in and execute it interactively?

Comment: Well, if I only SSH into the host, the connection goes through and when I run the script it completes good. When I try to add the script execution as soon as the SSH task is completed. It fails. My plan was basically this.....

I have written a bash script to deploy vCenters which work good. Next, is I want to deploy few VMs which can only be done with SSH to the ESXi. But the plan was, to run the bash script in RHEL, then invoke a sh script which would be scp'd to ESXi and then executed from there and once done return back to RHEL bash.

Comment: Looks like your script has a variable that has a value when you're logged in to the esxi system but doesn't have a value when you run it via ssh. Can we see the script up through the line with `-le` in it?

Comment: Hi, yes, the script has variable values to be used in ESXi. I am not sure what you meant by -le. Apologies if this sounds basic. Thanks

Comment: `ssh root@esxi-ip hostname` these commands output the right hostname of the ESXi server and then return to the BASH of RHEL

Comment: My guess is that somewhere in your `script.sh`, or in a script that it calls, there is a statement that looks something like `if [ $var1 -le $var2 ]`, Can you show us that line?

Comment: Yep, there are quite a few variable definitions. Few loops as well. `while [ $current -le $how_many ]`

Comment: Just before that `while` statement, please add `echo "current=$current how_many=$how_many"` and see if either of those variables appear empty.